# What is the fastest way to conditionally update data in a DataTable?

Tags: c#, datatable, conditional-statements, updates

I have DataTable full of data, with 3 columns - `col1`, `col2`, and `col3`.

I have to update data in `col3` (set it to `null`) when the value in `col3` is greater than 1000 or less than -1000.  I tried to iterate each row and check this condition, but it is too slow.  How do I improve the speed?

Comment: how often do you want to check the condition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presuming that the type of the column is `int`, you can use `Linq`:

```
var rowsToUpdate = data.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => r.Field<int?>("col3") > 1000 || r.Field<int?>("col3") < -1000);
foreach( DataRow row in rowsToUpdate )
    row.SetField<int?>("col3", null);
```

The field methods support nullable types and the `SetField` method allows to use `null`.

A little bit micro-optimization, just because you have mentioned that it's too slow:

```
var rowsToUpdate = data.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => {
        var val = r.Field<int?>("col3") ?? 0;
        return val > 1000 || val < -1000;
    });
```

Comment: The type arguments for method 'System.Data.DataRowExtensions.SetField<T>(System.Data.DataRow, int, T)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: @user1736332: Are you sure that you are using my code? `row.SetField<int?>...` I have also edited my answer to provide a lightly more efficient version.

Comment: My mistake, I've forgotten about <int?>  Everything works fine, thank you.